# directories and files to hdf5 groups and datasets

Tags: hdf5

This is probably a really stupid question, at least a very simple one. Please just point me to the right direction if it is not worth detailed reply.

My understanding is that HDF5 is good to store hierarchical data.  I use a file system to store my data --- root directory, sub-directories, data files (txt), and metadata text files.  The directory names are usually descriptive as well.  So it seems natural to bundle these data into a hdf5 file (or files) using directories as groups and data files as datasets.

My question is, are there any advantages in doing so? I want to to able to select and combine datasets by using groups and/or attributes (like SELECT from a database). Also, are there tools to do this?

Comment: You could try asking on ServerFault or SuperUser.  This does not appear to be a programming-related question.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, this is possible.

For example we have a web-application for visualization scientific data that relies on a single 250GB HDF5 File with 30.000 groups and each of those groups contains multiple datasets. The groups and datasets have attributes. The web-app only accesses this single HDF5 file to retrieve all information.

The advantage of using a HDF5 file is, that is quite portable and can be used in many different languages (C++, Java, python, etc). It's also really efficient for storing binary data and if you combine compression and chunking you can even inrease performance by using todays multi-core CPUs.

However HDF5 is quite different from RDBMS. You can't really use `SELECT` like in a database. You have to iterate (possibly recursively) through the groups/datasets. There are some libraries ([Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/),[PyTables](http://pytables.github.io/)) that are built on top of HDF5 and provide a higher abstraction. The downside is that you might lose some portability.

Another approach is to use a hybrid approach: 
You can store the meta-information in a RDBMS and the binary data in one or multiple HDF5 files. This might give you best of both worlds.

Here is also a list of useful libraries:

Python:

- [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) - simple pyhton hdf5 package
- [PyTables](http://pytables.github.io/) - high level abstraction over hdf5 dataset (support for tables)
- [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - Data Analysis Library supports hdf5 as backend.

C++:

- [HDF5 C++ API](http://hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/index.html)

Java:

- [JHI5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/JNI/jhi5/index.html) - the low level JNI wrappers: very flexible, but also quite tedious to use.
- [Java HDF object package](http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdf-object/index.html) - a high-level interface based on JHI5.
- [JHDF5](https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/JHDF5/JHDF5+%28HDF5+for+Java%29) -  high-level interface building on the JHI5 layer

Julia:

- [HDF5.jil](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl)

Matlab:

- [HDF5 Files](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/hdf5-files.html)

R:

- [rhdf5](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html) (Bioconductor)

GUIs:

- [vitables](http://vitables.org/)  - supports PyTables
- [HDF5View](http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/) - official HDF5 Java Viewer